# Can I wrap exception throwing code into a callback?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a node.js express app that uses [ldap.js](http://ldapjs.org/). However, ldap.js uses exceptions, e.g., in dn.js:

```
if (cur >= len || name[cur++] !== '=')
    throw invalidDN(name); // creates a new Error
```

In my client code, I use the `function(err,res)` pattern:

```
  client.search(groupDn, searchOpts, [], function(searchErr, res) {
    if(searchErr){
      callback(searchErr);
    } else {
      res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
        callback(null, entry);
      });

      res.on('end', function () {
        unbind(client);
      });

      res.on('error', function(err) {
        callback(err);
      })
    }
  });
```

The problem is that if I pass in an invalid `groupDn`, it throws an exception, which means that it doesn't go through my handler here.

I wonder if there is a general way to bring exceptions into a `function(err,res)` pattern - are there some automatic wrappers? (for now, I'm littering try/catches everywhere, but it's weird having to mix two distinct styles)

Comment: What do you mean by "bring exceptions" ?

Comment: Why not just check `groupDn` before you pass it in? Or just use a try/catch?

Comment: @ArthurKay This is just one specific example, there are other instances where the code throws. Since I'm new to node.js, I wonder if there is a generic pattern apart from try/catching manually all over the place.

Comment: @Cristy I wonder if there is a "wrapper" that would take a fragment like `library.doStuff("input", function(err, res) { ... })` and turn it automagically into something like `var doStuffCallback = function(err,res) { ... }; try { library.doStuff("input", doStuffCallback); } catch (e) { doStuffCallback(e); }`.